# Style-sheet of parent theme is not working in templates of child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have created a child theme in which I have created a template for the homepage. But stylesheet of the parent theme is not working on templates. How do I solve it? In functions.php I have written the following code-

```html
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

Is this correct? What changes I have to do on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
  $parent_style = 'parent-style';
  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
```

$parent_style = 'parent-style';
  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.